# Display Feature Lists and Subfeatures using Get-WindowsFeature

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I'm using Hyper-V Server 2019. (This is a free *Windows Server 2019 Core* package with the Hyper-V role installed. It's completely text-based by default - there's no GUI desktop as with regular Windows Server packages, excepting with 3rd party solutions that aren't part of this question.)

Many instructions for setting up various things on a server assume that a graphical tool is available. For example, the article [Prepare your environment for Windows Admin Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/deploy/prepare-environment)  shows how to perform [Step 2: Enable File Server Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/deploy/prepare-environment#step-2-enable-file-server-role) using the graphical tool normally available in other versions of Windows Server. Very few instructions include the Powershell method for doing things.

I have learned to use Powershell "cmdlets" to do various things, but I'm stuck on Step 2 above. I can figure out, I think, *how to install* the feature I need; however, for future reference, I want to be able to display the items I'm interested in. So...

To show a list of *all* features, I can enter `Get-WindowsFeature`. That, of course, brings up a long, scrolling list!

I can see by the diagram in the instructions that I need to see what's installed under "File and Storage Services". So, I do this:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.InstallState -eq "Installed"}
```

(or, alternatively: `Get-WindowsFeature | where Installed`)

In Powershell 5.1, this returns:

[image: Get-WindowsFeature: Installed Items List]

I can add a *Select-Object* pipe with the property *SubFeatures* and get this:

[image: Get-WindowsFeature: Installed Items List With SubFeatures]

But, what I really want is like the first image, but restricted to the *"File and Storage Services"* section and all of its SubFeatures, regardless of the *InstallState* value.

I have seen an `-ExpandProperty` parameter used with array-type results, but adding that anywhere in the cmdlet just gives me an error about that parameter not being available or that the *SubFeatures* property is not available. But...

`Get-WindowsFeature | Get-Member` shows the property as follows:

`SubFeatures               Property   string[] SubFeatures {get;}`

I have tried the following with the `-ExpandProperty` parameter:

`Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.InstallState -eq "Installed"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName, Name, InstallState, SubFeatures`

`Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.InstallState -eq "Installed"} | Select-Object DisplayName, Name, InstallState, -ExpandProperty SubFeatures`

`Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.InstallState -eq "Installed"} | Select-Object DisplayName, Name, InstallState | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SubFeatures`

Note: the only reason I used the *InstallState* on these was so that I didn't get a huge scrolling result. I was experimenting with getting the *SubFeatures* property before diving into how to get just the one *"File and Storage Services"* section, since I think that is going to require that I get the *SubFeatures* figured out first... Hmm...

Also, as an aside: Powershell 7 has a *Display Name* field in the output; however, it's blank. Only the *Name* and *Install State* fields have content. Interestingly, I can get the info by specifying it: `Get-WindowsFeature | where Installed | Select-Object DisplayName, Name, InstallState`, but it doesn't have the nice little `[X]` markers ;)

Either way, **what I'm looking for** is how to get a specific section (*File and Storage Services* here) and its expanded `SubFeatures` property, so I can easily see what's installed or available for that section using Powershell.

Oh, and to be clear, I did try `Get-WindowsFeature -Name FileAndStorage-Services`, which returned only that one item (without its SubFeatures):

[image: Get-WindowsFeature shows only one service]

---

This is the first several lines of my output if I use simply `Get-WindowsFeature`, including the `File and Storage Services` section:

[image: First several lines of Get-WindowsFeature output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the `SubFeatures` as output while querying `FileAndStorage-Services`, you can utilize the parent feature's `Name` property. By dynamically generating a list of its associated `SubFeatures`, you can ensure they are also included in the listing.

### PowerShell

```
$FeatureName = "FileAndStorage-Services";
$subFeatures = (Get-WindowsFeature -Name $FeatureName | Select-Object SubFeatures).SubFeatures;
$subFeatures = $subFeatures+(Get-WindowsFeature -Name $subFeatures | Select-Object SubFeatures).SubFeatures;
$combineFeatures = "$($FeatureName)|$($subFeatures -join "|")";
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $combineFeatures};
```

### Output

```
Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[X] File and Storage Services                           FileAndStorage-Services        Installed
    [X] File and iSCSI Services                         File-Services                  Installed
        [X] File Server                                 FS-FileServer                  Installed
        [ ] BranchCache for Network Files               FS-BranchCache                 Available
        [ ] Data Deduplication                          FS-Data-Deduplication          Available
        [X] DFS Namespaces                              FS-DFS-Namespace               Installed
        [X] DFS Replication                             FS-DFS-Replication             Installed
        [ ] File Server Resource Manager                FS-Resource-Manager            Available
        [ ] File Server VSS Agent Service               FS-VSS-Agent                   Available
        [ ] iSCSI Target Server                         FS-iSCSITarget-Server          Available
        [ ] iSCSI Target Storage Provider (VDS and V... iSCSITarget-VSS-VDS            Available
        [ ] Server for NFS                              FS-NFS-Service                 Available
        [ ] Work Folders                                FS-SyncShareService            Available
    [X] Storage Services                                Storage-Services               Installed
        [X] File Services Tools                         RSAT-File-Services             Installed
```

---

## More Detail

Executing this operation will unveil the values of the `SubFeatures`. In certain cases, employing the `Select *` approach can be particularly advantageous, as demonstrated in the output below.

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name $FeatureName | Select-Object *;
```

The remaining components are trivial, so I've provided a **supporting resources** section that you can explore for further learning, should you be interested or find the need to dig deeper.

#### Output

```
Name                      : FileAndStorage-Services
DisplayName               : File and Storage Services
Description               : File and Storage Services includes services that are always installed, as well as functionality that you can install to help manage file servers and 
                            storage.
Installed                 : True
InstallState              : Installed
FeatureType               : Role
Path                      : File and Storage Services
Depth                     : 1
DependsOn                 : {}
Parent                    : 
ServerComponentDescriptor : ServerComponent_FileAndStorage_Services
SubFeatures               : {File-Services, Storage-Services}
SystemService             : {}
Notification              : {}
BestPracticesModelId      : Microsoft/Windows/FileServices
EventQuery                : FileServer.Events.xml
PostConfigurationNeeded   : False
AdditionalInfo            : {MajorVersion, MinorVersion, NumericId, InstallName}
```

#### Supporting Resources

- [`Operators $( ) @( ) :: &`](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
- [`-Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @leanne ... I ran this right on Windows Server 2019 to get the desired output using PowerShell version 5.1. Happy to clarify further or on any of the other trivial logic I used to get the desired output, just let me me know.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I appreciate the depth of information! Sadly, however... I tried the code in your answer, both line-by-line and as a script. The result looked identical to your output - except the last line (with `File Services Tools`) is not present. Also, I know there are 'children' under `File and iSCSI Services`, too. Am I missing something else?

Comment: I also tried my own idea like this: `Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.Name -eq "FileAndStorage-Services" -or $_.Parent -eq "FileAndStorage-Services"}`. It gave me the same output as your script did: identical to your output except with the last line missing

Comment: Updated my question with the first several lines of my `Get-WindowsFeature` call. Seems like I don't have the `File Services Tools` under `Storage Services`; however, I do have a `File Server` entry under `File and iSCSI Services`. So... FWIW...

Comment: @leanne Oh I see what's up, the subfeatures have their own subfeatures. I worked it out, and about to edit answer with a new line of code, please refresh your screen to see the update in about 5 minutes or less. Let me know if this gets you all the detail you are after. I thought you meant only the subfeatures listed for `FileAndStorage-Services` only but this all makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@VomitIT - Chunky Mess Style's excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/1805685/114158), I wrote a script to retrieve the features recursively, using a command-line argument:

```
Param(
    [String]$Name
)

# Get a feature and its subfeatures recursively and add to an array
function GetParentAndKids($feature)
{
    $script:featureList += $feature

    $subFeatures = Get-WindowsFeature -Name $feature | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SubFeatures
    if ($subFeatures.count -eq 0) { return }

    foreach ($subFeature in $subFeatures)
    {
        GetParentAndKids($subFeature)
    }
}


$script:featureList = @();
GetParentAndKids($Name);
$script:featureList.foreach{Get-WindowsFeature -Name $PSItem}
```

Call as either:

```
PS> .\scriptname -Name parent-feature-name
```

```
PS> .\scriptname parent-feature-name
```

eg:

[image: Full Display of RSAT Feature And All Of Its SubFeatures]

and

[image: Full Display of FileAndStorage-Services And All Of Its SubFeatures]